# Fetching All Posts (200+) in a Category - Performance Issues?

Tags: get-posts, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I want to get the IDs of the 2 previous and 2 next articles in a certain category to show them as a "related videos" playlist. I know that there are the functions `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link`, which would do the job for me, but I want more than just 1 previous and 1 next link.

Imagine the following scenario:

- Post #001
- Post #002
- Post #003
- Post #004
- Post #005
- Post #006

On Post #001 I want to display #002 and #003.
On Post #003 I want to display #001, #002, #004 and #005.

```
$post_id = $post->ID; // current post id

$args = array('category' => $mycat, 'numberposts' => 200);
$posts = get_posts($args);
// get ids of posts retrieved from get_posts
$ids = array();
foreach ($posts as $thepost) {
    $ids[] += $thepost->ID;
}
// get and echo previous and next post in the same category
$thisindex = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
$prevvid = $ids[$thisindex-2];
$previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
$nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];
$nexttid = $ids[$thisindex+2];
```

I adapted and changed this code from the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_with_Previous_Next_Navigation).

And now the part that worries me: If I don't add a large number to `numberposts`, it will of course only fetch the standard amount of posts and therefore my code won't work the way I want it. I probably will never ever have more than 200 videos in one category. Do you think my solution is a bad idea regarding performance? I didn't find a trick elsewhere to show the adjacent posts.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Why you should want to fetch 200 posts if you are going to show 4 related posts maximum? Of course it is a bad idea: **always fetch only the data you need**. Instead of query for all posts and search in the results, make the correct query to get only the results you want. Also, you could run [`get_adjacent_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) four times or [`get_next_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post), which I think would be faster that query for 200 posts.

Comment: How can I modify the functions `get_adjacent_post` and `get_next_post` to give me two adjacent and two next posts? Or do you mean I have to apply a filter or a custom database query, because if so, I have no clue no how to get exactly those 4 posts I need. Thanks for your answer! Edit: Oh wait, so you mean I use `get_next_post` to get the ID of the next post, and then use that function again? I think that would work. Thanks for your input, that really makes sense now! I will try that and post my results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query for a large set of posts, but don't need full information for each you can use `'fields' => 'ids'`m see [Return Fields Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter).

In this case, I concur with comment, it might make more sense to simply retrieve adjacent post several times. You'll have to use `setup_postdata()` and `wp_reset_postdata()` since `get_adjacent_post()` doesn't allow you to set post explicitly. Unfortunately that function isn't too friendly to reuse or make use of SQL it generates.

Comment: Thanks alot, Rarst! This is how I got it to work and now there shouldn't be problems compared to my first codesnippet. I didn't think of using `get_adjacent_post()` in a post which I already fetched through `get_adjacent_post()`, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'offset' in your query to start two posts before the current one. So if you're iterating through posts and the current post is number 14, then offset by 12 and ask for 5 posts. This will give you numbers 12-16 which is what you need and nothing more.

```
$args = array(
  'category' => $mycat, 
  'numberposts' => 5,
  'offset' => 12,
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: I though also about `offset` in combination with `post__not_in` to exclude current post, but I think in the context of the question the position of current post is unknown.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your answer. I think this would be the perfect solution, but I got it to work with using `get_adjacent_post()` two times for my next and two times for my previous posts, which is still not as simple as your code, but my problem was finding the right offset. As @cybmeta said, I don't know at which place in the category my current post is, so I can't think of a way to get the right offset value. But then again I'm not a pro at PHP so someone might get this to work.